# Ringtone not working for contacts having no custom ringtone

Tags: android, phone-call, ringtone

I have 3 contacts (A,B,C). My default ringtone is 1. Contact A has 2nd ringtone. Contact B has 3rd ringtone. In the first time if Contact A make call it use ringtone 2. In the second time if B makes a call it picks ringtone 3rd ringtone. In the third time if C makes a call it picks 3rd ringtone only. But Contact C has no custom ringtone. So it should pick default ringtone that is 1(number 1 ringtone). But it picks wrong ringtone.